# TFlearn saving and loading module without network initalization

Tags: python, tflearn, recurrent-neural-network

Hi i have created a model and training it using TFlearn

```
# Network building
net = input_data(shape=[None, max_document_length])
net = embedding(net, input_dim=Vocabulary_size, output_dim=128)
net = simple_rnn(net, 512)
net = dropout(net, 0.5)
net = fully_connected(net, n_class, activation='softmax')
net = regression(net, optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')

# Training
model = tflearn.DNN(net, clip_gradients=0.)
model.fit(doc_vec, label, validation_set=0.1, show_metric=True, batch_size=100)

#saving the files
model.save('path')
```

But when i try to restore this model in a new file i am being required to give the entire Network Building again and load the model and predict.

```
net = input_data(shape=[None, max_document_length])
net = embedding(net, input_dim=Vocabulary_size, output_dim=128)
net = simple_rnn(net, 512)
net = dropout(net, 0.5)
net = fully_connected(net, n_class, activation='softmax')
net = regression(net, optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model = tflearn.DNN(net, clip_gradients=0.)
model.load('path')
print(model.predict_label(input))
```

I tried to pickle save both the net and model but it is throwing an error.
So what can i do to make sure i dont give the entire network and just save the model and restore it and use model.predict like the way it can be done using sklearn.